# Passing data to another Component with Input doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular

I want to send my data from one component to another one.
I'm using routerLink and I know that we can pass data in the URL like that:

```js
[routerLink]="['/edit', id]
```

and then read it using ActivatedRoute.

I was wondering if we can pass value to another component using @Input ? I tried but i didn't make it work.
In my A component i'm doing that:

```html
<button [name]="test" [routerLink]="['/edit']">Edit</button>
```

And in my B component i do that:

```js
@Input() name: string;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.name)
}
```

My console.log is showing me `undefined`....

Do you have any idea to help me to understand this ?

Comment: Two possibilities: (1). The `[name]` binding should be in the child component tag. Eg. `<app-child [name]="test"></app-child>`. Not in the `<button>` tag. If you don't have the parent-child relationship like this in the parent component, you can't use `@Input()` to pass data. (2). If you're actually binding `[name]` in the child component tag, make sure the `test` variable is defined some value in the component controller like `test = "sample value"`.

Comment: You cannot pass to data to another component's `@input` property using `routerLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<ComponentB [name]="'test'" [routerLink]="['/edit']">Edit</ComponentB>
```

Where `ComponentB` is the name of the component you're trying to pass the value to and access the value with `@Input`.
Or you have to define a local class variable named test which will hold the value.

`[]` uses the local class variable and pass the value of a specific variable to it.

Or you can do it like this. `name="test"` this doesn't compile the value passed it just take what is there.

Hope it's clear to you.

Comment: In general you are right, even tho the first variant with `[name]="'test'"` shouldn't be recommended, the second one `name="test"` is the way to go.

Comment: Updated my answer @MoxxiManagarm can you please take your downvote back. or suggest further edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method only works with parent and child component. Is the component from which you are trying to pass the data the parent component?
You can use Service instead.

Comment: That should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: Cannot add comment under the question due to low reputation :(